# How to print something around the values of a list?

Tags: python, list

My program allows you to write in times (they get put in a list) and the highest and lowest time of the list gets excluded and it then calculates the average of the remaining times.

Then I told the program to print out the times in the list and the average, the output looks something like this:

`[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1] average:x`

I want it to put parentheses around the highest and the lowest times of the average (the ones that are excluded). I'd also like it if the times were displayed without the `[]` around them, which would look something like this:

`(1.1), 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, (5.1) average:x`

I've been scanning the internet for a solution to this but I've had no success, I guess it's a very specific problem.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to do and if so how? I'd appreciate a pretty simple explanation, if possible, but I'll gladly learn something relatively advanced if I have to. (idk if it matters but I am using python 3)

Comment: could you post your code? then we can help you with what you need to change in your code to get what you want. you might want to take a look at [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to know how to format your printings

Comment: a) it is always possible, b) you should show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: In general, in programming, if something seems too hard, try to break it down into smaller questions.  So for example here... try to identify the max value, and focus only on that.  After that, try to store its location (which index it has in the list).

Comment: Also make sure you output a string. The square brackets indicate that you have a list of numbers that you still need to turn into a single string

Comment: You're unlikely to find a specific solution "scanning the internet". It sounds to me like you should instead be spending your time learning Python better (even though it may not be as easy and fun). Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to format the results, probably using f-string if you're using Python 3.6 or above:

```py
times = [ 6, 1, 8, 3, 9 ]                           # create list of times
mean = lambda x: sum(x) / len(x)                    # define average function
times = sorted(times)                               # sort our times
first_time = times.pop(0)                           # pop first time from list
last_time = times.pop()                             # pop last time from list
times_as_string = ", ".join(str(x) for x in times)  # e.g. "3, 6, 8" 
# now build and print out the string
print(f"({first_time}) {times_as_string} ({last_time}) average: {mean(times)}")
```

gives:

```
(1) 3, 6, 8 (9) average: 5.666666666666667
```

**Edit:**

If you are on an earlier version, you can use `%` syntax, e.g.:

```py
print("(%.2f) %s (%.2f) average: %.3f" % (first_time, times_as_string, last_time, mean(times)))
```

which will give:

```
(1.00) 3, 6, 8 (9.00) average: 5.667
```